# Converting a scasd to cmp dword

Tags: assembly, nasm

What is a way to convert this a scasd to cmp dword (I don't need to increment edi).

```
mov eax, 0x50905090
mov edi, edx
scasd
```

I tried

```
cmp dword edx, 0x50905090
```

and

```
cmp dword [edx], 0x50905090
```

and

```
cmp dword [edx-0x4], 0x50905090
```

All cause a segfault though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `ds` == `es` in your program?

Comment: Its a loop, so edx increments, and is suppose to equal 0x50905090 when it comes across that string in memory.

Comment: @SamRoberts: Are you sure that `edx` has a valid memory address?

Comment: `cmp dword edx, 0x50905090` won't segfault - any segfault in that code is elsewhere. Otherwise we need to know what's in `edx`. If `0x50905090` does not exist, `[edx]` will run off into invalid memory eventually. You may need to show more code.

Answer (score 2):

```
mov eax, 0x50905090
mov edi, edx
scasd
```

> What is a way to convert this a scasd to cmp dword (I don't need to increment edi).

The correct translation is

```
mov eax, 0x50905090
mov edi, edx
cmp eax, [es:edi]
```

or shorter

```
mov eax, 0x50905090
cmp eax, [es:edx]
```

You can not use the alternatives you proposed (using an immediate) because the order of the operands matters when doing a comparison.